# BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) occurs on main return

Tags: c++

my class:

```
template <class type>
class List{
    public:
        List(){
            _list = new type[10];
        }
        ~List(){
            delete this->_list;
        }       

    private:
        type* _list;

};
```

in main:

```
int main(){
List<std::string> l = List<std::string>();

return 0;
}
```

It happens only if I put non primitive variable in `<>` and dont use new.

I can avoid this by doing it like this:
`List<string> *l = new List<string>();`

What I'am missing? In my mind it should perfectly fine.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Explicit specializations must be introduced with `template <>`

Comment: oh Im sorry will fix it, I forgot to edit it when copied from cpp file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete[] instead of delete because you are allocating an array.